# IntelliJ doesn't recognize Java enum

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums, syntax-error

I'm working with **IntelliJ 14.1.4** and **Java SDK 1.8**. I've created an `Enum` but **IntelliJ** is not recognizing the code and it's showing the following error:

```
'class' os 'interface' expected
```

[image]

Are enum not supported by IntelliJ???

Comment: What language level is the project configured to?

Comment: Wow....it was configured at 1.4 level! Sorry, @Mureinik thank you!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is solved **configuring a correct language level**. In the case of enums, as enums are available since Java 1.5, the language level should be at least 5.

To configure the language level in IntelliJ go to **File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Project > Project language level** To ensure the chagnes are applied, restart IntelliJ, although in my case it wasn't necessary

[image]